# how to set particular payment method in magento programatically in methods.phtml using getsingleton?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, payment, session

I am trying to set particular payment method in Magento session programatically in `methods.phtml`. I know how to retrieve current selected payment method from Magento session using `getSingleton`. But I am not able to find out how to override the existing selected payment method in the session.
I want to directly update the session variable for payment method. Is there anything like `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMethod('$method')`. I have tried every other solution. If there is any function like this then please help me.

Comment: I just want to set payment method in magento session programatically ..

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here goes. You can try this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$methodCode = 'payment_code_here';
if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPaymentMethod($methodCode);
} else {
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod($methodCode);
}
$quote->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I noticed you are putting your variable in quotes. Not sure if you noticed that or not but it should look like.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMethod($method);
```

not

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setMethod('$method')
```